# How to use multiple dots in idnames

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties, operator

In add-on operators, you are required to give an idname to each operator. Commonly, it is `category.operator`. This results in calling the operator with `bpy.ops.category.operator`. When I tried to put two categories: `category1.category2.operator`, there was an error. Is there a way to put two categories in an operator idname?

I have the same question for registering Property classes: Normally, in register, I would put `bpy.types.Scene.name = PointerProperty(PropClass)`. When adding multiple categories like `bpy.types.Scene.category.name`, an error occurs that says `NameError: category is not defined`. Is there a way to put multiple categories on properties?

Comment: Part ii) is equivalent of `a.b = 3` which will throw an error if a is not defined or doesn't have property b.  Adding a class property equiv of `SomeClass.foo = property()` which gives an instance of SomeClass property foo. `SomeClass.foo.bar = property()` will only work if `SomeClass.foo` is defined (see python docs)  .. btw don't redefine the name property will cause errors.  Part i) is No too. The devs may change this is in the future, (unlikely to be any time soon)  For time being consider using underscores `foo_category.bar_operator`

Comment: @batFINGER Ok. Thanks. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score -1):

I tried

```
 bpy.types.Material['custom_float'] = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Test Property")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bpy_struct_meta_idprop' object does not support item assignment

>>> bpy.types.Material[custom_float] = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Test Property")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'custom_float' is not defined

>>> bpy.types.Material.custom_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Test Property")
```

The last one was the only one that worked
It looks like underscores are the way to go